# How to manually run any root query via Relay and cache on Relay?

Tags: javascript, relayjs

I just want to programmatically run some root queries via relay and fetch some data without going through component fragments.

Something like the following:

```
this.context.relay.fetch(Relay.QL`{ ... }`)
  .then((data) => doSomethingWithData(data));
```